# Formatting a one line if statement in Eclipse (2019)

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I understand that this question has been answered before, but those answers no longer apply to the current version of Eclipse.  If this is not the appropriate way to re-ask a question, I apologize in advance.

When I use shift+ctrl+f to reorganize a class I have the following happen to my one-line if statements

```
if (true) doThis();
```

changed to

```
if (true)
    doThis();
```

How can I make shift+ctrl+f auto organize to be like the first statement?

Comment: Yeah, follow that link. Under the "Control Statements" tab, look for the "Keep simple 'if' on one line" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

From the menu:

Window -> Preferences

In Preferences:

Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Click 'edit'
[image]

New Lines -> In control statements -> 'if else' -> Keep simple 'if' on one line

[image]

Comment: I am new to Eclipse.  This looks nothing like what is on my machine.  Is the Mac version significantly different?

Comment: I checked on the mac and the only difference should be in how to open the first menu(Eclipse->Preferences instead of Window->Preferences).  The look and feel is different, but all the menu items are named the same

Comment: I apologize, yes, you are correct.  I found it.  Thank you!!